# commitment declaration: total House space

Tags: visa, germany

I am working in Germany and have Blue  card visa. I want to invite my parents for summer vacation. For that i need to fill 'commitment declaration' or ás 'Verpflichtungserklärung' form.

As i am living in shared flate with two other main tenant. Total space is 104 m2 (4.5 rooms). But as per my contract i am paying for 83.5m2 (total 2.5 rooms, including my own room).

What should i write in form? (104 m2 or 83m2)

[image]

Comment: You must specify the amount that is **only available to you alone**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson How do you know that "only available to you alone" is the correct response?

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica Because you cannot use space that is not available to you. Here a lawers responce (in German) to the question about a shared household (the case of the OP): [Einkommen und Wohnraum bei 'Visum zur Eheschließung' (nicht VE!)](https://www.frag-einen-anwalt.de/Einkommen-und-Wohnraum-bei-Visum-zur-Eheschliessung-nicht-VE--f97211.html) *As far as sufficient living space is concerned, 12 m² of living space must be available per person for your sole use.  Rooms used by third parties are not taken into account.*

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica I couldn't find an official source for cases of a shared household (they only state 12 m² per person must be available), that is why I posted the statement only as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 
*[Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz](https://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_26102009_MI31284060.htm)* (Universal administrative fiat concerning the Residence Act) states:

> **2.4.2**
> Ausreichender Wohnraum ist […] stets vorhanden, wenn […] jede[m] Familienmitglied über sechs Jahren zwölf Quadratmeter […] zur Verfügung steh[t] und Nebenräume (Küche, Bad, WC) in angemessenem Umfang mitbenutzt werden können.
> Eine Unterschreitung dieser Wohnungsgröße um etwa zehn Prozent ist unschädlich.
> Wohnräume, die von Dritten mitbenutzt werden, bleiben grundsätzlich außer Betracht; mitbenutzte Nebenräume können berücksichtigt werden.

> **2.4.2**
> Adequate housing space is always given if every family member aged 6 and above […] is assigned 12 square meters of floor area and ancillary rooms (kitchen, bathroom) can be shared to an adequate degree.
> A deficit in the apartment’s size by approximately 10 percent of this area is harmless.
> Living areas used by third parties are generally not considered; shared ancillary rooms may be considered.

Your roommates live in neighboring rooms.
These are *their* living rooms (*Wohnraum*).
Living rooms used by third parties are (generally) excluded („Wohnräume, die von Dritten mitbenutzt werden, bleiben grundsätzlich außer Betracht“).
Therefore you should not write 104 sqm, the *apartment’s* total floor area (*Wohnungsgröße*).

On the other hand there is no general rule telling you to *always* count the floor areas of *shared* rooms (hall, bathroom, kitchen, etc.), too, so the absolute *lower limit* is merely your own room.

At any rate, your number should be ≥ N × 10.8 sqm (where N is the total number of family members to be).
Any “surplus” space is irrelevant to the processing of your application.

I recommend putting in the number you have *written evidence* of, i. e. what your tenancy agreement says.

Comment: The last heating bill (when you have central heating) will often contain the sqm value for each room.

Answer (score -1):

Always specify the space available to **you**.